# How get the number of the sentence that include a span or token in Spacy?

Tags: spacy

```
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span, Token
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["ner",'lemmatizer', 'attribute_rules', 'tagger'])
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")
matcher.add("obama", [nlp("Barack Obama"), nlp("Baracko Obama"), nlp("Baracko OBAMA")])
doc = nlp("BARACK OBAMA lifts America one last time in emotional. Farewell Baracko Obama baracko obama")
matches = matcher(doc)


spans = [Span(doc, match[1], match[2]) for match in matches]
print(spans)

matches
```

The results are:

```
[BARACK OBAMA, Baracko Obama, baracko obama]
[(15955766757638404248, 0, 2),
 (15955766757638404248, 11, 13),
 (15955766757638404248, 13, 15)]
```

how to get the sentence or the number of the sentence in the doc that includes `(15955766757638404248, 0, 2), (15955766757638404248, 11, 13)`, and     `(15955766757638404248, 13, 15)`.

I want for example to get (15955766757638404248, 0, 2) in sentence 1 and `(15955766757638404248, 11, 13)`, and     `(15955766757638404248, 13, 15)` in sentence. Is this possible in Spacy?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.sent` property on a token or span to get the corresponding sentence. (If your span covers multiple sentences, the first is returned.) So given your data you can do something like this:

```
match_id, start, end = (..., 0, 2)
span = doc[start:end]
print(span.sent)
```

It sounds like you want to know if things are in the same sentence more than the sentence number, so this should be enough. If you actually need the number of the sentence, that isn't provided directly, but you can add it easily enough by counting the sentences or using [extension attributes](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines/#custom-components-attributes) on spans or similar.

Comment: I am looking for both the number and the sentence itself. With sent I get the sentence but I am trying to figureout how to add the number of the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like to get the sentence number you can iterate through the sentences and compare the span's start and end token indices to find the sentence containing the span -

```
for sent_idx, sent in enumerate(doc.sents):
    if span.start >= sent.start and span.end <= sent.end:
        return sent_idx
```